# while creating subnet group in 3 tier architecture , and calling the subnet id's from VPC main.tf , its not reading the values

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

[Terraform 3 tier subnet group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03dYN.png)

i am calling the values of subnet id from another main.tf file which is in another module

Comment: Please post code and error as **formatted** code blocks, not screenshots.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1):

Your `subnet_ids` can't be a string reference to other module file:

```
subnet_ids = ["${path.module}/../path/to/file/tf"]
```

Instead you have to pass the actual `subnet_id` values as a variable list to your module:. For example:

```
variable "subnet_ids" {}

# and then

subnet_ids = var.subnet_ids
```

Comment: what if i dont want to use variables ?

Comment: @MayankMajreti There is no other way.